# Deploying applications in old distributions compiled in the new distribution

Tags: version, compatibility, deployment

I have a binary built on `ubuntu 20` (in a docker container FROM ubuntu:latest)
What if I want to run this binary, for example, in `ubuntu 16`?

I know that it is possible to face the fact that the version `libc.so` in ubuntu 16 is not compatible with `libc.so` in ubuntu 20, the binary was linked to, and I will get an error at runtime something like `GLIBC symbols is not found`.

What is the best practices in such cases? Static linkage with sys libs and building on each target platform are not considered.

How about providing all the system shared libraries (`libc`, `libpthread`, `ld.so` and so on) from the build platform to the target platform?
And my application running in ubuntu 16 will use `libc` from ubuntu 20, with which it was linked. (I will specify the path to the desired `libc` via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, for example)

What problems can I face with this approach?

Comment: This seems like a lot of hassle, why not compile it for 16?

Comment: @Panki let's assume that the deployment will take place on multiple platforms (18, 16, 14, RHEL 7, RHEL 8, etc.). It turns out that you need to compile on each platform separately? I am looking for best practices when it is possible to compile only once

Comment: Yes, you need to target a specific platform while compiling binaries. You could look into container technologies, although that creates a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to provide everything necessary to run a “new” binary in an old distribution ends up being complicated and somewhat fragile; if you’re interested, take a look at the Steam runtime or the Flatpak runtimes for example. It’s arguably worth it for a whole ecosystem, but I think it’s too much effort for a single binary.

Since you already have a container descriptor capable of building your binary, I’d recommend adapting that for all your target distributions; that way you can build binaries which have the correct dependencies everywhere, and you’ll know if the dependencies need to be adjusted before your users find out for you.

There are other options, not necessarily exclusive.

You could opt to provide your binary in a container image. If the container is well-built, the overhead can be reduced to a minimum — effectively, the overhead required to provide the runtime necessary for your binary, so equivalent to the option you’re considering now, and far less fragile.

Another option to consider is to build the binary statically, or on something like a lowest common denominator (*e.g.* RHEL 7). You might run into issues with the availability of old dependencies on new distributions, but those can often be resolved in a nicer way than the first approach.

Comment: Yeah, I'd also build for RHEL7 since it's a good lowest common denominator.